# Plotting the eigenvalues of n x n matrices against the number of eigenvalues (n)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to write a script in python which generates matrices with even ranks 2 to 10 (so with steps of 2) and calculates its eigenvalues. I succeeded in doing this. I am able to to generate the matrices with elements a across the main diagonal and elements b on the diagonals one off the main diagonal and calculate the eigenvalues:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def Huckel(a,b):
    for n in range(2,10,2):
         huckel_matrix = np.zeros(shape(n,n))
         np.fill_diagonal(huckel_matrix,a)
         huckel_matrix[np.arange(n-1),np.arange(1,n)] = b
         huckel_matrix[np.arange(1,n),np.arange(n-1)] = b
         eigen_values = np.linalg.eigvalsh(huckel_matrix)
Huckel(0.0,-1.0)
```

However, I would like to also scatter plot these eigenvalues (y-axis) against the rank of the corresponding nxn matrix (x-axis) (at given a = 0.0 and b = -1.0). So, I want to write a line which takes the eigenvalues and scatterplots them against the ranks of the corresponding matrices (2,4,6,8), but I don't exactly know how to do that.

I am very new to Python and I am not really sure how to achieve this. I think it should be written in the for loop but I don't know how. Hopefully, one can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want a scatterplot with eigenvalues on y-axis and number of eigenvalues on x-axis.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def Huckel(a,b):
    res = []
    for n in range(2,10,2):
        huckel_matrix = np.zeros((n,n))
        np.fill_diagonal(huckel_matrix,a)
        huckel_matrix[np.arange(n-1),np.arange(1,n)] = b
        huckel_matrix[np.arange(1,n),np.arange(n-1)] = b
        eigen_values = np.linalg.eigvalsh(huckel_matrix)
        res.append(eigen_values)
    return res


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for eigval in Huckel(0.0,-1.0):
    ax.plot([eigval.size] * eigval.size, eigval, 'bo')
```

[image: Eigenvalues by matrix size]

Comment: Yes this is what I wanted to do. Apparently I am very rusty with my math these days, totally forgot that an nxn matrix has n eigenvalues :#

Answer (score 0):

I want to be careful here as I don't fully understand the math behind your desired output, however, you're not doing anything with your calculations. I've modified your code to store your results, which you could then plot as you see fit.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



def Huckel(a,b):
    huckle_out = []
    for n in range(2,10,2):
        huckel_matrix = np.zeros(shape= (n,n))
        np.fill_diagonal(huckel_matrix,a)
        huckel_matrix[np.arange(n-1),np.arange(1,n)] = b
        huckel_matrix[np.arange(1,n),np.arange(n-1)] = b
        eigen_values = np.linalg.eigvalsh(huckel_matrix)
        huckle_out.append(eigen_values)
    return huckle_out


my_huck = Huckel(0.0,-1.0)
```

Which returns a list:

```
Out[27]: 
[array([-1.,  1.]),
 array([-1.61803399, -0.61803399,  0.61803399,  1.61803399]),
 array([-1.80193774, -1.2469796 , -0.44504187,  0.44504187,  1.2469796 ,
         1.80193774]),
 array([-1.87938524, -1.53208889, -1.        , -0.34729636,  0.34729636,
         1.        ,  1.53208889,  1.87938524])]
```

Comment: Hi, yes I am sorry, I maybe could've stated my question more explicitly. I'm having trouble with the plotting part itself. I want to write a line which takes the eigenvalues and plots them against the ranks of the corresponding matrices (2,4,6,8), but I don't exactly know how to do that.

Comment: 'Against the ranks' Is where you lose me. Are you looking to plot all of them in the same plot, or have an individual plot for each?

Comment: All in the same plot: the eigenvalues of a 2x2 matrix at n =2, the eigenvalues of a 4x4 matrix at n=4, the eigenvalues of a 6x6 matrix at n=6, etc. (Sorry for my bad english)